# jquery create object dynamic not working

Tags: jquery, html, jvectormap

I need the output as

```
{       'US-CA': '#084365',
        'US-TX': '#084365',
        'US-CO': '#00a2e8',
        'US-NM': '#00a2e8',
        'US-WY': '#00a2e8',
        'US-NE': '#00a2e8'
    }
```

For this I used the following code:

```
   var output = [];

$('.vectordata').find('.varc').each(function(i){
            var t = $(this);
            regioncode = t.find('.regioncode').val();
            color = t.find('.color').val();
                    var obj2 = {}
                    obj2[regioncode] = color;
                    output.push(obj2);

    }
```

But the output I received is

[image]

Please help me fix the dynamic object creation

Comment: You are getting array of objects in output but you need literal object. This is because you are pushing single object in one array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need the array just put it in the object

```js
 var output = {};

$('.vectordata').find('.varc').each(function(i){
            var t = $(this);
            regioncode = t.find('.regioncode').val();
            color = t.find('.color').val();
            output[regioncode] = color;
                   

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to get output as JSON object like below:

```
{       'US-CA': '#084365',
        'US-TX': '#084365',
        'US-CO': '#00a2e8',
        'US-NM': '#00a2e8',
        'US-WY': '#00a2e8',
        'US-NE': '#00a2e8'
}
```

so, in order to serve your purpose you need to declare an object and put the values into object as {key:value} pair. Don't need any array to store the object again. You can follow samuellawrentz answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
       var output = {};

    $('.vectordata').find('.varc').each(function(i){
                var t = $(this);
                regioncode = t.find('.regioncode').val();
                color = t.find('.color').val();
                        output[regioncode] = color;

        }

console.log(output);
```

You were pushing `objects` into `Array`. Make `output` as object.